# Django-concurrency AttributeError

Tags: python, django, concurrency, django-admin

I'm trying to add the [django-concurrency project](https://github.com/saxix/django-concurrency) to the admin interface of a django 1.6.8 webapp. The application deals with storing data about objects we call "Configuration"s. We'd like to prevent issues caused by concurrent edits to these Configurations.

So far, I've done my best to follow the [documentation](https://django-concurrency.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html) for integrating with the Admin interface, but I'm getting a nasty AttributeError:

```
Internal Server Error: /test/common/configuration/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 137, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 82, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 85, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 78, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 85, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 78, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 85, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 78, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 85, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 78, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 78, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 78, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1196, in render
    _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 288, in result_list
    'results': list(results(cl))}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 266, in results
    yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 258, in __init__
    super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 185, in items_for_result
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 254, in lookup_field
    value = attr(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrency/admin.py", line 37, in action_checkbox
    get_revision_of_object(obj))))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrency/api.py", line 23, in get_revision_of_object
    return getattr(obj, get_version_fieldname(obj))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrency/core.py", line 22, in get_version_fieldname
    return obj._concurrencymeta._field.attname
AttributeError: 'Configuration' object has no attribute '_concurrencymeta'
[21/Nov/2014 20:29:51] "GET /test/common/configuration/ HTTP/1.1" 500 368613
```

So far, I've changed the ConfigurationAdmin class to inherit from ConcurrentModelAdmin as described [here](https://django-concurrency.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html#id1).

```
class ConfigurationAdmin(ConcurrentModelAdmin):

    form = forms.ConfigurationForm
    change_list_template = 'admin/configuration/change_list.html'

    ...
```

I also changed `{{ obj.pk }}` to `{{ obj|identity }}` in `delete_selected_confirmation.html` as directed in the [documentation](https://django-concurrency.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html#id3).

Does anyone know how to solve this? I can provide more code from other files if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I forgot to add a version field to the model.

```
from concurrency.fields import AutoIncVersionField
class Configuration(models.Model):

    version = AutoIncVersionField()
```